# Exception handling practices in JSP EL custom functions

Tags: jsp, function, exception, taglib

I've defined a [custom function](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html#wp71289) to wrap the [Jackson object mapper](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.4.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html#writeValueAsString%28java.lang.Object%29), but am unsure what to do with all the checked exceptions?

In concrete terms my question is: how should I resolve the TODOs in this code?:

```
public static String toJSON(Object o) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(o);
    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

The matching taglib is currently:

```
<function>
    <description>Converts an object to JSON</description>
    <name>toJSON</name>
    <function-class>uk.co.ondemand.whitelabel.taglibs.ScriptingFunctions</function-class>
    <function-signature>java.lang.String toJSON(java.lang.Object)</function-signature>
    <example>
      var theAsset = ${wls:toJSON(asset)};
    </example>
</function>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just declare them in the `throws` clause of the method until you know how/where to handle them.

```
public static String toJSON(Object o) throws IOException {
    return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(o);
}
```

Comment: Is there some resource that discusses where I might handle them (in the specific context of a custom JSP Tag Handler)?

Comment: Define an `<error-page>` in `web.xml` if you want to make it a bit more friendly towards the enduser and keep an eye on the logs. Those kind of errors are developer's faults, not enduser's faults.